# How to convert SVG 'c' curve to a list of cubic bezier curve?

Tags: javascript, svg, bezier

I have a path as follow:

`d="m 0,0 38.913,455.481 c 7.122,83.37 6.816,164.779 13.005,236.077 18.924,218.078 232.099,308.663 268.399,493.918 16.874,86.119 -37.253,229.874 -42.144,323.022 -7.527,143.381 69.579,142.669 104.526,244.648"`

I don't quite understand how it is represented.

I guess it is converted as a list of multiple simple cubic bezier curves, but how? What should i take as control points, start point, end point each time?

And what coordinates here exactly are relatives? And relative to what?

I am totally new to SVG graphics and (it seems to me that) w3 references doesn't give enough details on those points.

If it can help my goal here, is to represent this curve with javascript in a canvas point by point.

Comment: what is so difficult about reading the spec - it's pretty darn clear: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands

Comment: well, not really. At the beginning I thought that mean that it was a Bezier curve with 12 points (12th degree) which I implemented before I realized i should divide it in multiple cubic curves. So my point is, as mentioned in my comment, that this chapter is poorly written and lacks of crucial details.

Comment: I agree, the spec is not clear regarding what it means when you follow C or c with more than three points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Convert via yqnn's svg path editor

An easy way to rewrite your pathdata `d` attribute is to insert the string in [yqnn's svg path editor](https://yqnn.github.io/svg-path-editor) and
**toggle the minify** option checkbox twice.

All omitted command letters (for repeated and implicit commands) will be added for a more readable `d` string.

### 2. Convert via `getPathData()`

[`getPathData()`](https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData) is not yet supported by any major browser.
So you need a polyfill like [Jarek Foksa's pathdata polyfill.](https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill)

1. Parse the path with `getPathData()`.
   All repeated or implicit commands will be split to separate commands:
   Implicit relative `l` lineto:

```html
m 0,0 38.913,455.481 
// result:
M 0,0 l 38.913,455.481
```

The first `m` command in a `d` attribute is in fact always absolute. Since we have converted the implicit `l` command – we can change the first moveto to uppercase `M` command letter (can facilitate path concatenation).

Repeated `c` [(cubic polybézier)](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands)

```html
c 7.122 83.37 6.816 164.779 13.005 236.077   
18.924 218.078 232.099 308.663 268.399 493.918 
16.874 86.119 -37.253 229.874 -42.144 323.022 
-7.527 143.381 69.579 142.669 104.526 244.648  
// result:
c 7.122 83.37 6.816 164.779 13.005 236.077   
c 18.924 218.078 232.099 308.663 268.399 493.918 
c 16.874 86.119 -37.253 229.874 -42.144 323.022 
c -7.527 143.381 69.579 142.669 104.526 244.648
```

2. Apply the pathData with `setPathData()`

```js
let pathData = path.getPathData();
path.setPathData(pathData);
output.value = path.getAttribute('d');
```

```css
svg{
height:20em
}

textarea{
width:100%;
min-height:20em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/path-data-polyfill@1.0.4/path-data-polyfill.min.js"></script>


<svg viewBox="0 0 382.7 1753.15">
        <path id="path" d="m 0,0 38.913,455.481 c 7.122,83.37 6.816,164.779 13.005,236.077 18.924,218.078 232.099,308.663 268.399,493.918 16.874,86.119 -37.253,229.874 -42.144,323.022 -7.527,143.381 69.579,142.669 104.526,244.648&quot;" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="2" />
</svg>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

### 3. Manual approach

All you need to know is the number of values/parameters for each command type and split the command values into chunks accordingly:

`M`: 2 values - succeeding values are treated as implicit `L` linetos.
`L`, `T`: 2 values
`V`, `H`: 1 value
`C`: 6 values
`S`, `Q`: 4 values
`A`: 7 values

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have [cubic bezier curves](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands), not quadratic ones. The specification text explains what the control points are and what they are relative to (the end point of the previous move/line/curve generally)

Comment: And here for instance the tree points just after `c` would be control1, control2, end? and the first start point would be the second point after `m`?

Comment: Yes to the first question, not sure what you mean by "the second point" in the second question.

Comment: just to be sure, if i understand well `c 1,1 2,2 3,3 4,4 5,5 6,6` would become `C 1,1 2,2 3,3 C 7,7 8,8 9,9` ?

Comment: Yes. Why not just create an SVG file and try it?